# Custom UITableViewCell highlighting issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a XIB file for my custom UITableViewCell and changed its height to 88. (twice the default size because I want to put a lot of views in it). I did no particular change except that one.

However something weird happens when I select a row at runtime: only the first vertical half of the cell is highlighted. What can I do to make the cell fully highlighted when selected?

Comment: please put a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means only your cell content is increasing but not cell frame. Your cell height is just as it was before(44).
Select UITableView in storyboard or nib file and change the UITableViewCell height to 88. Hope this solves your problem